# I need help crafting a tricky regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write some Python code that will parse some text files that use the `'#'` character to start a comment.  I am looking for a way to remove trailing comments from a line in the file.

At first I tried `str.rfind('#')` but that was not sufficient because some of the files have comments starting with `"##"` or have multiple comments (eg. `#comment1 #comment2`).

I next tried a few combinations of `re.sub` to remove them but ran into problems where lines in the files contain the comment character inside of a string (eg. `"attempt #3"`).

In these files, as with C, string literals are surrounded by double quotes and character literals are surrounded by single quotes.

What I am looking for is a way, in Python, to strip trailing comments from a line without bothering them when the comment character is inside of single or double quotes.

Here are examples of the lines that are causing me problems for which I need an all-encompassing solution:

```
variable_name  ## sometimes used  ## variable:L"name####":

variable_name = "Update Gen11 E5 ROM version to 1.34_04_25_2023 (#24201)"

file_name  #comment1 #comment2
```

The output for these should be:

```
variable_name

variable_name = "Update Gen11 E5 ROM version to 1.34_04_25_2023 (#24201)"

file_name
```

In the first case, the `'#'` inside the quotes is seen as part of the comment and is removed because there is a prior `'#'` that is not inside of quotes.

In the second case, the `'#'` is inside of quotes and there is no prior `'#'` so the line is left unaltered.

In the last case, the line is stripped staring with the first comment because that `'#'` is the left most not inside of quote.

Comment: Please add more details on example. What should be matched and what should not? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that text that starts with `##` is not to be removed? If in the example you gave, all text from the first `#` to the end of the line is removed, would that somehow be wrong?

Comment: It seems, like your input is not a text file, but in fact a Python source file. If this is the case, consider using proper parser, and not regex. Remember, that python has multiline string constants, two different quotes for strings and quotes escapement. All this will lead to increasingly difficult to write and maintain regex.

Comment: I added more information ...
I added what the expected output is and explained why I expect the output to be that way.

Comment: Looks like an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem

Comment: The file is not a Python source file. My simplistic examples just make it look that way.
The files are actually UEFI DSC, INF, DEC, and FDF files which look a lot like INI files but are not exactly the same.

Comment: Are strings in this domain always delimited by double quotes, or are single quotes allowed as well?  What you want here is "the first # that is not inside a quote", right?

Comment: @TimRoberts, double quotes always surround strings, but single quotes could be used for a character.  This follows the C syntax.
Yes, what I am trying to do is strip from the first '#' character not inside of quotes to the end of the line.

Comment: clops, when responding to requests for clarification it's always best to edit your question rather than elaborate in comments. Questions should be stand-alone, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Comment: @SebastianWozny do you still think this is an XY problem with the information I have added?  Not sure if you gave me the -1 vote or not, but I did research this and have

Comment: So you need to parse double quotes as well as comments. Need a regex for that ?

Comment: What if there is a multiline string, like in Python where it is delimited with `"""`?

Comment: Also, can the quotes be escaped? Like `var = "val\"with quote" #comment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex in a sub().  Replace with `\1` group 1.

```
\#.*|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^"'#]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/UhyIwd/1

Explained

```
    \# .*                            # Comment all until end of line
 |                                 # or,
    (                                # (1 start), Non - comments 
         "
         (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*        # Double quoted text
         "
      |  '
         (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*        # Single quoted text
         ' 
      |  [\S\s]                           # Any other char
         [^"'#]*                          # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string
    )                                # (1 end)
```

A code sample

```
import re

pattern = r"""\#.*|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^"'#]*)"""

target = '''
variable_name  ## sometimes used  ## variable:L"name####":
variable_name = "Update Gen11 E5 ROM version to 1.34_04_25_2023 (#24201)"
file_name  #comment1 #comment2
'''

res = re.sub( pattern, r'\1', target)
print(res)
```

Output

```
variable_name
variable_name = "Update Gen11 E5 ROM version to 1.34_04_25_2023 (#24201)"
file_name
```

Comment: This is  the first time I've seen a regular expression defined with triple quotes, though I know little of Python. Why did you do that and what is the implication for `\\ ` and `[^'\\] ` (`\\ ` is clearly not a backslash)?. Also, does `#` need to be escaped at the beginning?

Comment: Also, can you explain why you use `[\S\s]` in the last alteration? It feels like `[^"'#]*` should be enough, but I'm not sure on your intentions there.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I believe ``\\ `` is an artifact of explanation (with implied `x` flag), and in fact should mean exactly a backslash.

Comment: That was my understanding of triple quotes, but I don't understand the purpose of `\\ ` since there are no backslashes in the example strings, yet they clearly are needed.

Comment: @markalex - This is a way to allow continuous, no break  parsing. `| [\S\s][^"'#]`  is a common technique that allows for errors in balanced delimiters to pass through without disturbing anything else that would cause breaks in the parse.

Comment: For some reason when I copied this to my code as follows:

pattern =""" \#.*|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^"'#]*)"""

I would get the following error when I tried to run it:

Exception has occurred: error
missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 6

I got it to run, and it appears to run correctly, by adding another closing parenthesis to the end of the expression:

pattern = """ \#.*|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^"'#]*))"""

Comment: @Cyberclops - I'll add a python code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand comments begin with the first hash mark (`'#'`, aka pound sign, octothorpe) that is not within a parenthetical expression.

You can convert matches of the following regular expression to empty strings provided you are confident there will always be an even number of double quotes:

```
\ *#[^\"]*(?:(?:\"[^\"]*\")[^\"]*)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rYbqSF/1)

The idea is that `'#'` falls within a parenthetical expression if and  only if there are an odd number of double quotes between it and the end of the string.

Note I've changed each `[^\"]` at the link to `[^\"\n]` so that the  results for multiple examples could be displayed. I've escaped the space character at the beginning of the regex merely to show that it is present.

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
\ *#          match zero or more spaces then '#'
[^\"]*        match zero or more chars other than dbl quotes
(?:           begin outer non-capture group
  (?:         begin inner non-capture group
    \"        match dbl quote
    [^\"]*    match zero or more chars other than dbl quotes
    \"        match dbl quote
  )           end inner non-capture group
  [^\"]*      match zero or more chars other than dbl quotes
  )*          end outer non-capture group and execute >= 0 times
$
```

Comment: It seems like this solution expects even number of quotes after #. But it will miss line like `code # comment with " quote`. Shouldn't you check evenness of quotes before #?

Comment: @markalex, I have assumed the string is well-formed in the sense that it contains an even number of double quotes. Therefore, if a hash mark is followed by an odd number of double quotes it must also be preceded by an odd number of double quotes, so it must fall within a parenthetical expression.